# Prove that the union of the interior of a set and the boundary of the set is the closure of the set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'll denote closure of A with $\overline{A}$, $A^\circ$ as the interior of A, $\partial A$ as the boundary of $A$ and $A'$ as the accumulation points. I'm trying to prove the following:

$$\overline{A}=A^\circ \cup\partial A$$

Is this a valid proof?

Take $x \in A^\circ \cup \partial A$ then $x \in A^\circ$ or $x \in \partial A$

if $x \in A^\circ$ then $x \in \overline{A}$

if $x \in \partial A$ then $x \in \overline{A} \cap\overline{(X\setminus A)}$ thus $x \in\overline{A} $ so $A^\circ\cup\partial A\subset\overline{A}$

Take $x \in \overline{A}$ then $x \in A' \cup A$ thus $x \in A'\setminus A$ or $x \in A^\circ$

if $x \in A'\setminus A$ then $x \in \overline{(X\setminus A)}$ so $x \in \overline{A}\cap\overline{(X\setminus A)}$ and $x \in\partial A$ so $x\in A^\circ\cup\partial A$

if $x \in A^\circ$ then $x \in A^\circ\cup \partial A$ so $\overline{A}\subset A^\circ\cup\partial A$

Comment: The fourth line doesn't seem right to me. It leaves out the points in $A'\cap (A-Int(A))$. They belong to $(X-A)_C$ though, so what follows still holds.

Comment: fyi, the latex command for the bar is \overline and for the set difference backslash you're trying to do it's \setminus. Like this $\overline{(X\setminus A)}$.  While we're at it, $X^{\circ}$ and $\partial X$ for interior and boundary might make things a little easier on the eyes, too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the flaws suggested in the comments this I think (IMHO) this is an easier way to approach some parts of the proof.

To prove the line that $x \in ∂X \implies x \in \overline A $

Suppose $x$ is in the boundary of $A$ and $x$ is not in some closed set $B$ which contains $A$. Then $x \in B^c$ which is open and hence there is a neighbourhood $V_x$of $x$ which entirely avoids $A$ leading to a contradiction since every neighbourhood of $x$ must contains elements in $A$ and $A^c$.

Similar reasoning can be used to show that $x \in \overline A \implies x \in A^{\circ}$ or $x \in ∂X$.

Suppose $x \in \overline A$ and $x$ is an exterior point of $A$. Then there is a neighbourhood of $x$ which entirely avoids $A$. But then there is a closed set which contains $A$ but not $x$. This leads to a contradiction since $x \in \overline A \implies x$ is in every closed set containing $A$. Then $x$ is not an exterior point of $A \implies x$ is either an interior point or a boundary point of $A \implies x \in A^{\circ}$ or $x \in ∂X$

Comment: Maybe a little late, but I don't understand in the first part how such a contradiction leads us to the fact that $x\in \overline A$, can you help me?